# Splitting a list in a Pandas cell into multiple columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a really simple `Pandas` `dataframe` where each cell contains a list. I'd like to split each element of the list into it's own column. I can do that by exporting the values and then creating a new `dataframe`. This doesn't seem like a good way to do this especially, if my `dataframe` had a column aside from the list column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[[8,10,12]],
                        [[7,9,11]]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[x[0] for x in df.values])
```

Desired output:

```
   0   1   2
0  8  10  12
1  7   9  11
```

Follow-up based on @Psidom answer:

If I did have a second column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[[8,10,12], 'A'],
                        [[7,9,11], 'B']])
```

How do I not loose the other column?

Desired output:

```
   0   1   2  3 
0  8  10  12  A
1  7   9  11  B
```

Comment: `df[0].apply(pd.Series)` works for your example.

Comment: @Psidom `apply(Series)` would work but [perhaps we could do better](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432583/4909087).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can loop through the Series with `apply()` function and convert each list to a `Series`, this automatically expand the list as a series in the column direction:

```
df[0].apply(pd.Series)

#   0    1   2
#0  8   10  12
#1  7    9  11
```

*Update*: To keep other columns of the data frame, you can concatenate the result with the columns you want to keep:

```
pd.concat([df[0].apply(pd.Series), df[1]], axis = 1)

#   0    1   2  1
#0  8   10  12  A
#1  7    9  11  B
```

Comment: How can I not loose an additional column (modified original question)?

Comment: You need the `pd.concat()` method. See the update!

Answer (score 25):

You could do `pd.DataFrame(df[col].values.tolist())` - is much faster ~500x

```
In [820]: pd.DataFrame(df[0].values.tolist())
Out[820]:
   0   1   2
0  8  10  12
1  7   9  11

In [821]: pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df[0].values.tolist()), df[1]], axis=1)
Out[821]:
   0   1   2  1
0  8  10  12  A
1  7   9  11  B
```

---

Timings

Medium

```
In [828]: df.shape
Out[828]: (20000, 2)

In [829]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(df[0].values.tolist())
100 loops, best of 3: 15 ms per loop

In [830]: %timeit df[0].apply(pd.Series)
1 loop, best of 3: 4.06 s per loop
```

Large

```
In [832]: df.shape
Out[832]: (200000, 2)

In [833]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(df[0].values.tolist())
10 loops, best of 3: 161 ms per loop

In [834]: %timeit df[0].apply(pd.Series)
1 loop, best of 3: 40.9 s per loop
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer instead.