# Why are my arrays in cells from pd.Dataframe typecasted to strings?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I created a pd.Dataframe with 1 np.array in each cell of the columns "time series" and "time stamps", then I saved it as a csv and opened the csv in another script.
My df looks like this:

[image]

The weird thing is that after opening the csv again, the two columns containing arrays are typecasted to strings.

So instead of something like this [1, 2, 3], every array looks like this "[1, 2, 3]".

Before saving and re-opening, everything was fine. I saved my df like this:

```
gss_epochs.to_csv(path_or_buf = path + "df.csv")
```

and opened it like this:

```
gss_epochs = pd.read_csv(path + "df.csv", sep = ",")
```

I haven't really found a solution for my problem online. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks a lot in advance!
Merle

Comment: `csv` is inherently 2d - rows and columns.  Have you looked at the `csv` file?  The original lists are formatted as strings, and reloaded as such.

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't know that! Is there another way to save the dataframe (aka not as csv) so I don't have this problem?

Comment: Maybe you can convert the lists to additional columns or rows?  That way, you'd get a more standard dataframe to work with.  See e.g. [Splitting a list in a Pandas cell into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40924332/splitting-a-list-in-a-pandas-cell-into-multiple-columns)

Comment: One option might be to pickle your dataframe, then unpickle it when you want to use it with your other script.

Comment: Okay I'll try that, thanks y'all! :-D